# Hashed password is not recognized after changing it

Tags: c#, hash, authentication, passwords

I have hased my password right there on in the registration.aspx. having this code in my business layer:

```
public static string CreateSHAHash(string Phrase)
    {
        SHA512Managed HashTool = new SHA512Managed();
        Byte[] PhraseAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Phrase));
        Byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PhraseAsByte);
        HashTool.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
    }
```

and this code in the register page:

```
scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
```

Having the codes above, the password are being hashed in the DB and it is working fine when I log in with this code:

```
protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            if (password == BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text))
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUser.Text;
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Logged In')</script>");
                Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
        }
```

However when I change it having this code in my `changepassword.aspx`, its not letting me in with my new password.

```
protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        str = "select * from UserData ";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txt_cpassword.Text) == reader["Password"].ToString())
            {
                up = 1;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        if (up == 1)
        {
            con.Open();
            str = "update UserData set Password=@Password where UserName='" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            com.Parameters["@Password"].Value = BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txt_npassword.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lbl_msg.Text = "Password changed Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_msg.Text = "Please enter correct Current password";
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it get updated in the database? Is the password hash shorter after you have changed it? Maybe 50 is truncating the hash?

Comment: good idea! lemme check

Comment: you are a legend. any way that i can make it up to you? @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen

Comment: Also consider a design where you keep a history of passwords, i.e., do not update the existing password but insert a new password record. Then, creating the first password is exactly the same as creating subsequent passwords - both use the same insert command. A password history can protect against users always using the same password.

Comment: hey good idea @Polyfun. do you have any reference or samples on how can i make that happen? thank you! :)

Comment: No examples. You will need a password table with a DateTime column in the primary key, so you can select the latest password.

Comment: I will post an answer and you can mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: will search for that. thank you @Polyfun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the 50 truncates the hash.

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
```

---

On a sidenote i see that your solution is very open to SQL injection.

```
 "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
```

A user can write sql statements in the textbox, and hijack your database, create his own tables or drop the whole database. You should always parameterize the queries. I see that you did that to the Update statement, but you should consider doing it for all of your variables.

This quickly creates a lot of code, so i would also consider making an SQL wrapper, that wraps in all of the things you repeat. When you are done refactoring it could look something like this:

```
var sql = new SqlWrapper("select Password from UserData where Username = @username", txtUser.Text);
var dataSet = sql.Execute();
```

Then you can hide all of your connectionstring, commands++ behind this wrapper and only tell the wrapper what you actually care about.

You should also consider using a salt for your password. If you and I have the same password, the hash will be the same. A salt will fix this problem.

A good article about password security -> https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Not convinced about needing a SqlWrapper. I find this just make the code more difficult for someone else to understand, as they have to wade through your (poorly written?) wrapper code to get to something they already have already of (the .Net libraries). SqlParameters can be created and added in one line.

Comment: It's called a facade pattern. Making something that is complex, simple. As a developer, i read through loads of code everyday. The fewer lines of code i have to read through to get to the point, the better. Write good facades, that makes sense, and that is dynamic enough for your use. It's good practice, and encouraged ->  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

SqlParameters, SqlConnection and SqlCommand is abstracted away.... a good thing...

Comment: I understand that, but in my experience the average programmer is not very good at writing facades, and I do not think it is warranted for something as well understand as System.Data.SqlClient, which is already a façade. By all means, create a façade for your own libraries.

Comment: If the average programmer you have worked with are not very good at writing façades, then they should not be architects. If you know how to write good façades, you should definitely make them, so that your less good developers don't have to fiddle with things that they don't know anything about. System.Data.SqlClient can do loads of stuff. Which is good. But rarely needed. If these developers are not good, then you should help them make less mistakes while dealing with a big library, by making them a façade, or better, teach them to be better developers :) Internal seminars and peer to peer :)